# Django: Not responding to the changes after git pull

Tags: python, django, git, digital-ocean

I have a Django 1.6 project using Gunicorn+Nginx. I have cloned it to my web server (DigitalOcean) and it looked fine and the site was working.

Then I made some changes on the projects in my PC and pushed to GitHub. Then I downloaded the updates by using      git fetch -all and     git reset --HARD. The project in the server side was successfully overwritten (I confirmed this by opening the file where there are changes). However, when I open my site in the browser, it only reflected some of the changes. Specifically:

1. the HTML/CSS part is updated as the newest version;
2. BUT, the urls.py and settings.py still followed the old setting. For example, I created a "/login" url in the newest version. But when opening the browser, it showed error. It seemed that it is still reading the setting.py and urls.py of the old branch.

I tried     git branch, it showed that I am currently working on the master one, which is the newest one;

I also try restarting the Gunicorn and Nginx. Nothing different observed.

Could anyone please enlighten me? Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. git reset --hard will just remove any changes to your current branch you may have. Try `git fetch --all && git pull --rebase` or `git fetch --all && git pull`.
2. Try removing all '.pyc' files. An easy command to do that is (assuming you're in the root directory of your project): `find . -name '*.pyc' -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Removing .pyc files is a very good thing to try. If this doesn't work, say so and we'll try something else.

Comment: Thanks @abeaamase and Jon Kiparsky for the quick replies. I tried the 2 things mentioned above. And then I restarted nginx+gunicorn, but now the problem becomes: "Bad Request(400)"...

Comment: Then I did some search and set the ALLLOWED_HOST to be my domain name and now the problem is fixed and I guess the setting of ALLOWED_HOST is the cause of the bad request 400. Thank you guys for the help. @abeaamase .